# Converting JSON in Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm beginner to C # and ASP.NET , however I have some doubts.

It has a serialized dictionary que was stored in the database with :

```
    var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(filters.ToDictionary(item => item.Key.ToString(), item => item.Value.ToString()));
```

After serialized this dictionary it is stored in the database , because I'll use information in a view (PopUp in asp.net).

My difficulty is deserialize these values ​​that are in the database to put them back in a dictionary. I tried:

Code used to get the information in the database :

```
<asp:Literal ID="lblFilter" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilterJson")%> ' />
```

The only way I get to collect the information in the code behind was:

```
object filter = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("lblFilter")).Text);
```

However , I can't use it with iterations and not even a Dictionary. With Dictionary used the following code:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> filters = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
```

That is when I need `.Add` a `key` and `value` in my dictionary not only chain I have a great What is the value que get no `Literal` :

```
((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("lblFilter")).Text
```

How can I make to converting correctly ? Thank you.

Comment: are you able to change the server code? you might be better binary formatting it and sending it raw.

Answer (score 1):

To deserialize a JSON-string you can easily use the following code:

```
Dictionary<object, object> filters = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<object, object>>(yourJSONString);
```

You have to use `object` instead of `string`, because if you have a list in your JSON-string you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I used the framework Json.NET regardless package in project.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Getting .aspx values:

```
string serialize = @"" + ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("lblFilter")).Text
```

To deserialize I used code bellow:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(serialize);
```

Obs.: the `JsonConvert` method belongs to the import package.